# jQuery: What is the meaning of "? true:false"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was studying jQuery and at some point I encounter this code at one of the examples of some random sites.

```js
$("#schedchkall").prop('checked', ($('.betchkbox:checked').length == $('.betchkbox').length) ? true : false);
```

Now my question is what is the meaning of `? true : false` ? What's the use of it?

Comment: It's the ternary operator, think about it as a short if...then--else  https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Using the conditional operator like this is an anti-pattern. The whole `(...) : true : false` expression can be replaced by the `...` part.

Comment: ow! now I know. Thank you experts!

Comment: A single DOM selection would be better than two overlapping selections. `$(".betchkbox:not(:checked)").length === 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the [Conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

It's a simplified `if` statement.

You could "translate" that line into this

```
var condition;
if($('.betchkbox:checked').length == $('.betchkbox').length) {
    condition = true; // -> ?
} else {
    condition = false; // -> :
}
$("#schedchkall").prop('checked', condition);
```

Comment: or just `$("#schedchkall").prop('checked', $('.betchkbox:checked').length == $('.betchkbox').length);`

Answer (score 0):

It means if `$('.betchkbox:checked').length == $('.betchkbox').length)` is true, it will return true such that it becomes `$("#schedchkall").prop('checked', true);`

If it is false, it becomes `$("#schedchkall").prop('checked', false);`